# Apparent wavelength received by observer in doppler's effect

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, kinematics, relative-motion, doppler-effect

I have a few doubts about Doppler's effect.

- Does the apparent wavelength received by the observer depend upon whether the observer is moving or not?
- $λ_{apparent}=\ \frac{v_{sound}\pm v_{source}}{f}$. For any general case, is this formula correct regarding the apparent wavelength received by the observer?

Edit: (Example where observer is moving to prove that wavelength is independent of observer's velocity)

- suppose velocity of sound is $v$ and approaching observer has velocity $u$, then $λ=\frac{\left(v+u\right)}{f'}$ where, $f'=\frac{\left(v+u\right)}{v}f$, so that when we substitute $f'$, the apparent wavelength does come out to be independent of velocity of observer.

Please tell me if I am right in thinking so!

Comment: Is $u$ the source velocity or observer velocity in your example?

Comment: source is at rest,while observer is coming towards the source with a velocity u

Comment: Ok, so when you write $\lambda$, you have used $v_{source}$ in your formula, but in the example, you are using observer's velocity.

Comment: the above formula is for any general case, the point is that is what i want to prove, that the wavelength is independent of the observer's velocity, that is why i gave an example where the observer is moving. and yes you understood it right

Comment: So in your general case formula, you have written $v_{source}$ in the numerator, but in the example, if you use the same formula, shouldn't $v_{source} =0$? I think, for the general formula, you should write $λ_{apparent}=\ \frac{v_{sound}\pm v_{observer}}{f}$ and then it would make sense. Finally this numerator would cancel with the frequency term which you will write subsequently.

Comment: Basically apprarent wavelength is the velocity of sound **relative to observer** divided by apparent frequency.

Comment: Yeah so the last comment was what i was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @JohnWick please allow me to [link your earlier related post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/628362/254821). The wavelengths of the wave under discussion as observed by the observer and source are indeed, in general, not identical. Please see corresponding [the lecture notes from MIT OCW](https://web.mit.edu/8.286/www/lecn18/ln01-euf18.pdf) for a comprehensive and detailed (clean) deduction of the Doppler effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems to be right except the calculation of $λ$. that will be perceived by the observer is given as

$λ=\frac{V}{f’}$ (all three are relative or apparent i.e. as perceived by the observer)

So instead of $V$, we write $V-U$ (since the observer is moving away the relative velocity will become slower, you’ve written $V+U$) this is the mistake you’ve made.

So no, it won’t be independent of observer’s velocity. I recommend seeing some of animation on Doppler effect for better visualisation.

Comment: So basically apparent wavelength is the velocity of sound relative to observer divided by apparent frequency, this is always true right?

Comment: Yes that is always true

Answer (score 0):

The formula of Doppler Effect goes as follows:$$f_o=\Bigl( \frac{ v\pm v_0}{v\pm v_s}\Bigl).f_s$$

Here ,

$f_o$=frequency  measured by observer

$f_s$=frequency of source

Note:

When observer moves away from source - sign is used in numerator and if observer moves towards source + sign is used in numerator.

When source moves away from observer + sign is used in denominator and if source moves towards observer - sign is used in denominator.

Basically,

O.$\rightarrow$          S.$\rightarrow$  $f_o=\Bigl( \frac{ v+ v_0}{v+v_s}\Bigl).f_s$

O.$\rightarrow$          S.$\leftarrow$  $f_o=\Bigl( \frac{ v+ v_0}{v- v_s}\Bigl).f_s$

O.$\leftarrow$           S.$\rightarrow$ $f_o=\Bigl( \frac{ v- v_0}{v+v_s}\Bigl).f_s$

O.$\leftarrow$           S.$\leftarrow$  $f_o=\Bigl( \frac{ v- v_0}{v-v_s}\Bigl).f_s$

[Arrow indicates direction of velocity of observer(o) and source(s) and written beside it is the formula for that corresponding situation]

As you can see frequency measured by observer depends both on observer's velocity and also on source's velocity. So since speed of sound doesn't change we can say by $v=f\lambda$ that wavelength will also depend on both the velocities of source as well as observer.

By the way the formula you used would be valid for a stationery source i.e A SPECIAL CASE.